# .NET 8 Blazor add a component

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

In my new .NET 8 Blazor solution, I have 2 projects, `LIU.Website` and `LIU.Website.Client`. Those projects were created by Visual Studio 2022 Preview.

[image]

Now, I want to add a component for the [Markdown editor](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorMarkdownEditor) and I follow the instructions to configure the component. In the `LIU.Website`, I opened `App.razor` and add the CSS in the header

```
<link href="/_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/css/alert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/css/easymde.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and the JavaScript at the bottom of the page

```
<script src="/_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/js/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/js/easymde.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/js/markdownEditor.js"></script>
```

When I render a page with the component, the page is not executing the JavaScript but the CSS and the JavaScript are loaded. The component uses `JavaInterop` to call the JavaScript to configure the `textarea` as the Markdown Editor.

[image]

I put a breakdown but the application is not calling this function at all.

Comment: If you are making active calls, and they are not being executed, presumably there are errors.  What errors does the Console in your browser's Dev Tools give?

Comment: There is no errors in the dev tools

Comment: Either you need to call a function yourself, and have not, or the function is being called and not run (i.e. it's not found).  I do not see how you could possibly not have an error.